# php regex expression no greedy

Tags: php, regex

I have to extract array from html block , specifically just the tools (without the word tools and the match need to be no greedy), the problem is the html block takes two forms, once it's like this:

```
<p>tools :<br>
 1 Hex Key (or two Hex key)<br>
 1 screww drivers<br>
 1 hammer <br>
 1 drill </p>
```

and the second form is like this:

```
<p>"tools :
 1 Hex Key (or two Hex key)
 1 screww drivers
 1 hammer 
 1 drill "</p>
```

i try with this regex , but i don't succeed:

```
  $tools = "<p>tools :<br>
  1 Hex Key (or two Hex key)<br>
  1 screww drivers<br>
  1 hammer <br>
  1 drill </p>"

 $tools_array = preg_match_all('#<p>tools:([^<>]*<br\s*/?>[^<>]*)+</p>#s', 
 $tools);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do what you want:

```
^(?!\s*<p>tools\s*:)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(<br|</p|$))
```

It looks for a line which does not start with `<p>tools:`, then matches characters (using a non-greedy match) until it sees one of `<br`, `</p`, or the end of the line. The match is returned in group 1. We use the `m` flag to allow `^` to match start of line in a multi-line string.

In PHP:

```
preg_match_all('#^(?!\s*<p>tools\s*:)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(<br|</p|$))#m', $tools, $tools_array);
print_r($tools_array[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1 Hex Key (or two Hex key)
    [1] => 1 screww drivers
    [2] => 1 hammer
    [3] => 1 drill 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jd0cD)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$tools = explode("\n",$tools);
```

the result is :

```
Array
 (
      [0] => <p>tools :
      [1] =>   1 Hex Key (or two Hex key)<br>
      [2] =>   1 screww drivers<br>
      [3] =>   1 hammer <br>
      [4] =>   1 drill </p>
  )
```

then unset the first element and delete every tag in another elements.

```
unset($tools[0]);
$tools= array_map(function($val){return strip_tags($val);},$tools);
```

the result is :

```
 Array
 (
      [1] =>   1 Hex Key (or two Hex key)
      [2] =>   1 screww drivers
      [3] =>   1 hammer 
      [4] =>   1 drill
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach....
Without using **RegEX**

*snippet*

```
$tools = "<p>tools :<br>
  1 Hex Key (or two Hex key)<br>
  1 screww drivers<br>
  1 hammer <br>
  1 drill </p>";
  $search = ['<p>','</p>','<br>', 'tools :']; //Add more words to be removed
  $filteredStr = str_replace($search, '',$tools);
  $res = explode(PHP_EOL,$filteredStr);
  array_shift($res); // Removing empty element at the beginning of array
  print_r($res);
```

*Output*

```
Array
(
    [0] =>   1 Hex Key (or two Hex key)
    [1] =>   1 screww drivers
    [2] =>   1 hammer 
    [3] =>   1 drill 
)
```

Live [Demo](https://3v4l.org/v52EY)

Reference
[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
[array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)